# Parse JSON string values

Tags: javascript, json

I have a big problem, I hope somebody can help me solve. I am trying to make a Linkedin sharing function from the API. The content there is in the JSON is postet perfectly on LinkedIn. But the problem is that a person cannot see what there is posted in the posting box. I uploaded my share button to my domain, if somebody wants to test it:

> http://www.vouzalis.com/wwwroot/stackTest.html

As I see it, I did everything the API ask:

> https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin

I cannot see what else I am missing? Does anybody have a clue of what there could be wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
        api_key: myAPIKey
        authorize: true
        onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
        lang : da_DK
    </script>



</head>
<body>

    <script type="in/Share">
    </script>

    <script>
        // Setup an event listener to make an API call once auth is complete
        function onLinkedInLoad() {
            IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", shareContent);
        }

        // Handle the successful return from the API call
        function onSuccess(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }

        // Handle an error response from the API call
        function onError(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }

        // Use the API call wrapper to share content on LinkedIn
        function shareContent() {

            // Build the JSON payload containing the content to be shared
            var payload = {
                "comment": "Check this awesome website out",
                "content":  {
                    "title": "Hello",
                    "description": "StackOverflow",
                    "submitted-url": "https://www.stackoverflow.com",
                    "submitted-image-url": "http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/03597/POTD_chick_3597497k.jpg"
                },
                "visibility":  {
                    "code": "anyone"
                }
            }

            IN.API.Raw("/people/~/shares?format=json")
            .method("POST")
            .body(JSON.stringify(payload))
            .result(onSuccess)
            .error(onError);
        };


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```